The head of a screw is missing on one side of the spigot outdoor
I want to avoid creating a much larger issue (due to water), but I would like feedback on how to fix the damaged screw on the spigot.
My thought would be to turn off water, allow it to drain, and then remove the spigot from the side that still has a good screw (hoping it doesn't break as well..). Then use a screw extractor with a portable drill and pray I don't bounce around and create more damage. After that, if the hole is too large I need to repair the hole with something like a dowel and wood glue? Then I can place the spigot back with two outdoor quality screws.
I assume I might need that plumbers tape to apply on the thread before putting it back.
Still worried that the pipe behind this wall is not accessible (its in the wall, both sides), so rotating the spigot off to get access to the screw has me concerned of damaging the internal pipe.
Please help me not make this a larger issue by providing feedback on what would be the best way to do it right the first time. Like, do I need to put anything on it to ensure water doesn't damage the house (some sort of barrier?).
Thank you!


You've pointed out some concerns about removing the spigot, and you're right. You could loosen the connection other than the spigot and not be able to get to it to tighten it back up, like a sillcock.
I would drill another hole in the flange of the spigot just above the existing hole and screw the spigot to the wall using the new hole. Then get some caulk that matches your siding and caulk around the edge of the flange and the wood. Put a dap of caulk in the old hole.

Might be worth drilling and screwing above and below the sheared screw too.

@Huesmann  I thought about that first but it looks like it was a good size screw with a large head. Those spigots can be abused by people yanking on the hoses so I went with a new hole in the spigot.

No, I meant drill new holes in the flange above and below the existing one (I'd assumed you meant a single hole above or below).  If we want to really go overboard, we could put a collar around the whole thing and screw it to the wood block!

Just be careful not to overshoot too much when drilling.  I'd drill deep with the right size for a pilot hole, then open out the hole in the metal.  That gives better centration than the other way round and means you're removing less material as you drill the clearance hole, so you can easily go gently

@Huesmann  Got it..

Mostly harmless. Those screws are just holding the spigot to the side of the house, to keep it from being pulled or twisted in a way that might damage the pipe.
Since it's just a screw into wood, feel free to put in another screw to replace the missing one.

Oh, well if it isn't an issue for the house then I may not worry as much lol. I had a water leak once and now I'm all nervous about anything water related. Currently the Spigot doesn't move at all when you twist it on or off, so it seems secured to the wall even though one screw head is sheered. Thank you for the response!
